# Reactive spring authorization server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use spring-authorization-server, and it seems to work very well, but as i can see it relies on servlet api which makes it not usable with spring webflux and netty. Does anyone knows how to tackle this? Or maybe correct me if my assumption is wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebFlux is not on the roadmap for Spring Authorization Server.

From the Spring Authorization Server GitHub repository:

> We are strictly focusing on a Servlet implementation for the initial set of features that would qualify for a MVP version. We haven't decided whether we'll provide a WebFlux version at this point.
> Quite honestly, I'm not convinced it's needed. The client and resource server(s) are the most active, whereas, the authorization server is not as active as it simply issues a token and may validate a token, which is limited activity between the many interactions that follow between a client and resource server after a token is issued.

Quote taken from [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/152).